# Taco zone controller - blinking yellow light?

Tags: thermostat, heating, hydronic

I have a Taco ZVC406 zone controller. This is the type which takes signals from multiple thermostats and uses relays to switch on the heating loop pump.

I am using a Honeywell CT87K thermostat on one zone. Hooking it up resulted in the *yellow signal light for that zone persistently blinking yellow when there is NO call for heat*. The zone does work OK and there is no blinking when heat is on.

I have an identical setup on another ZVC controller with the same thermostat, and no problem.

This thermostat does NOT require a C-wire, and in fact as far as I can tell won't even accept one. It will take R, W, Y (RW are the "T/T" thermostat switch signal, and Y seems to be some sort of boiler signal which my system doesn't have).

I've read other posts about the same symptom but those were with Nest thermostats which would take a C wire if available and apparently were sucking some current from the TT signal, causing the problem.

Since the other zones don't have the same issue, I suspect there is some failed or failing component but I'm not sure what to look for.

[The instructions](http://www.taco-hvac.com/uploads/FileLibrary/102-397.pdf) don't mention anything about this.

Comment: Have you called Taco technical support (really? how much support is necessary for eating tacos?? :D ) to see if they can help you diagnose the issue?

Comment: @FreeMan no, but that is a good suggestion